# What is this old wheel brick?

Tags: part-identification

What is this old wheel brick? Wheels are also available in about the half size. They have metal axles.

[image: Example Photo]

Comment: The question seems to be more about the wheels than the center brick.  I'm guessing that Kurbo assumed it was one part, and not an assembly.

Comment: @chicks I disagree, because how are you supposed to know if the wheels have metal axles without taking them apart? Still, I admit that this is not exactly a duplicate. But this question has already been smashed 2 times with a dupe-hammer anyways.

Comment: I did assume that they were always bundled together - I didn't think that they would have separate part numbers.

Comment: Yes, it is. Early 1960's a British consortium with new Lego parts, 2 size of wheels, turn-table & towbar. The axle bricks contains Nylon tubes, these hold wheel axle & as  not fixed can turn. 1st have red underside,  then came with   clear there, see red tube across & black at ends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some variants registered on bricklink, but judging by the name and the presence of the brick in the middle, I guess the closest is:
[Wheel with 12 Studs and Axle Cam with Light Gray Tire Smooth - Large (715a / 36)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=715ac02&name=Wheel%20with%2012%20Studs%20and%20Axle%20Cam%20with%20Light%20Gray%20Tire%20Smooth%20-%20Large%20(715a%20/%2036)&category=%5BWheel%20&%20Tire%20Assembly%5D#T=C)

The small version you mention is probably:
[Wheel with 4 Studs and Axle Cam with Light Gray Tire Smooth - Small (7039b / 132-old)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=7039bc02&name=Wheel%20with%204%20Studs%20and%20Axle%20Cam%20with%20Light%20Gray%20Tire%20Smooth%20-%20Small%20(7039b%20/%20132-old)&category=%5BWheel%20&%20Tire%20Assembly%5D#T=C)

Comment: The wheels can be removed from the brick

Comment: That was mostly why I went with a variant with the axle.

Comment: Thank you! @Henriksupportsthecommunity

Answer (score 3):

Henrik covered wheels, so I'll just mention the brick used to attach these - [Brick, Modified 2 x 4 with Wheels Holder, Trans-Clear Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=7049b#T=C)

[image]

As noted on Bricklink there could be some variations of this brick:

> Several versions of this brick exist. Bush colors have been reported as red, black, milky white, and mixed colors, as well as a version missing the middle bush.